# I want to use variable length input with dynamic RNN of tensorflow, but I don't know how to padding

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

As an example, input tensor is a batch size 3, a maximum time sequence length 4 and dimension of feature value is 2

[ [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8] ],
[ [9, 10] ] ]

, And in order to make it an input to RNN

[ [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8] ],
[ [9, 10], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0] ] ]

I would like to have a form like this, is there a good way to do it?
Since we assume that the tensor to be input to this RNN is the feature amount extracted by another neural network before entering RNN, I would like to know a method that will not break the calculation graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think may need **tf.train.batch** (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch) and 
 use **dynamic_pad=True**.

Comment: Assuming that the batch size is 32, is it possible to input the feature value obtained from that batch into tf.train.batch and use batch_size = 32 and dynamic_pad = True?